# How to check if azure resource exists in PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault

I am trying to check if an azure key vault already exists in a resource group using PowerShell. **If the vault with the same name already exists even in the deleted state** I only want to receive a user friendly message saying Key Vault already exists or catch the exception if there is any. I don't want the terminal to blow up with errors. If the key vault does not exist I want to create a new keyvault.

I have the following code:

```
$KeyVaultName = "Key Vault Name"
$ResourceGroupName = "Resource group name"

$KeyVault = Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $KeyVaultName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if($null -eq $KeyVault){
    New-AzKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Location "Switzerland North"
}
else{
    Write-Host "$KeyVaultName already exists"
}
```

After executing the code I am getting this error message on the terminal:

***New-AzKeyVault : A vault with the same name already exists in deleted state. You need to either recover or purge existing key vault.***

I also tried using the following code as well:

```
if (!(Test-AzureName -Service $KeyVaultName))
{  
    New-AzKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Location "Switzerland North" 
}
```

It gives me the following error after execution:

***Test-AzureName : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to set the default subscription.***

Though I only have one subscription being used.

Can someone please tell me if I am doing something wrong here ? Can you please provide me with an efficient way to achieve this ?

Comment: In general, you could remove the ```-ErrorActionPreference SilentlyContinue``` and wrap ```Get-AzKeyVault``` in a ```try ... catch``` block instead to handle the exception. However, according to the documentation for ```Get-AzKeyVault``` there's also an ```-InRemoveState``` switch you can specify that might help - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvault?view=azps-7.0.0

Comment: @mclayton Thank you very much for your answer. The InRemoveState did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
$KeyVaultName = "keyvaultname"
$ResourceGroupName = "resourcegroupname"
$KeyVaultLocation = "keyvaultlocation"
$KeyVault = Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $KeyVaultName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if($null -eq $KeyVault){
    $KeyVault = Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Location $KeyVaultLocation -InRemovedState -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($null -eq $KeyVault) {
      New-AzKeyVault -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -VaultName $KeyVaultName -Location $KeyVaultLocation
    } else {
      Write-Host "$KeyVaultName exists but is in soft-deleted state"
    }
}
else{
    Write-Host "$KeyVaultName already exists"
}
```

Essentially what we are doing here is first checking if the Key Vault exists and is in active state. If we do not find any Key Vault, then we are checking if the Key Vault is in soft deleted state. If no results are found, then we are proceeding with creation of new Key Vault.

However, please note that Key Vault name is globally unique so it is quite possible that your `New-AzKeyVault` Cmdlet fails.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This works perfectly ! One final question, what can we do in case the key vault name existed globally. What condition should we add ?

Comment: How is it possible to check if an azure resource NAME exists globally in order to prevent an error from appearing in the powershell terminal.